# My counting variable will not increment beyond the value of 1 vba

Tags: vba, excel

My apologies for the confusion. Here goes an attempt to clarify:

Pseudo code:

1. For each item in list one (i) --> set counting variable to zero
2. Check each item in list two (j)
3. If list one item matches list two item then increment counter AND store value
4. If count == 1 then do stuff (list one item found in list two ONE time)
5. If count ==2 then do other stuff (list one item found in list two TWO times)
6. Next item

My problem is that the "ticker" variable gets incremented inside of the equation, but the value of the variable never changes from 1 to 2. Thus, the statement "If count = 2" never fires. My picture shows where I have broken the code at each iteration of the j For loop to monitor the value of the "ticker" variable. On the iteration when the "ticker" should change from 1 to 2 the equation inside of the IF statement shows that it is incremented, but the variable's value, shown in the locals window, does not change.

[image]

Code:

```
For i = LBound(SAPanArray) To UBound(SAPanArray)
            anString = Trim(Split(SAPanArray(i), " ")(0))
            ticker = 0
            Set a = FindNextEmpty(Sheets("SAPdata").Range("F4"))

            If IsInArrayC(anString, SAPanArray) = 0 Then
                Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((a.Row), (a.Column)).Value = Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 9).Value
                Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((a.Row), 7).Value = (Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 10).Value) * 2000
                Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((a.Row), 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            Else
                For j = LBound(SAPbulkArray) To UBound(SAPbulkArray)
                SAPbulkArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("SAPdata").Range("F4:F" & (Sheets("SAPdata").Range("F" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)))

                    If InStr((SAPbulkArray(j)), anString) > 0 Then
                        ticker = (1 + ticker)
                        dupArray(ticker) = Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Value
                    End If

                    If ticker = 1 Then
                        If ((Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 10).Value) * 2000) <> (Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Value) Then
                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((a.Row), (a.Column)).Value = Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 9).Value
                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((a.Row), 7).Value = (Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 10).Value) * 2000
                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((a.Row), 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
                        End If
                    ElseIf ticker = 2 Then
                        summer = (dupArray(1)) + ((Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 10).Value) * 2000)
                        If summer <> dupArray(2) Then
                            If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 11)) Then
                                Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Value = Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 11).Value
                            End If

                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 11).Value = Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Value
                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 11).Font.Color = vbWhite
                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Value = ((Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((i + 3), 10).Value) * 2000) + Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Value
                            Sheets("SAPdata").Cells((j + 3), 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
                        End If
                    End If

                Next
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: what happens if you declare the ticker=0 before the for loop?

Comment: That's a truckload of code. You should narrow down on the issue to make a question people will want to answer. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: This is beside the point, but this line is bad form: `Dim counter, counter1, counters, duplicateCount, ticker As Long`.  (all variables *except* `ticker` are implied as Variant type. only `ticker` is `Long` data type).  Your other declaration statements suffer the same fate.

Comment: Also, the screenshot doesn't really illustrate the problem you describe. Have you put a breakpoint on `ticker = (1+ticker)` in order to see how many times that statement is executing? And then to observe whether its value changes (as it should)? I suspect your problem is elsewhere, and merely diagnosed improperly.

Comment: On closer review, @Sami's point is a good one.  At each iteration of `i`, you reset `ticker=0`. Now, you could still increment within `j` loop, but right now it's not clear what cases are observed as failure. Add simple `Debug.Print` statements ahead of the `ticker = (1+ticker)` statement and see if that helps narrow down the logical error(s)?

Comment: The screenshot does exactly show your mistake. Try: `Dim i As Byte: i = 1: Stop: i = (i + 1): Stop`. At the first `Stop` `i` is 1. Evaluating the braces `(i + 1)` becomes correctly `(1 + 1)` which is 2. but that does not mean that `i` is 2 at that point (just hovering over `i` shows `i = 1`). And at the second `Stop` (now `i` IS 2) it evaluates to `(i + 1) = 3` which is correct because `i` is 2 and `(2 + 1)` is 3. I am sure that the code workes perfectly (at least this problem) and there simply is no error at that part as most computers are good at increasing integers by one :D

Answer (score 1):

```
            For i = LBound(SAPanArray) To UBound(SAPanArray)

                anString = Trim(Split(SAPanArray(i), " ")(0))
                ticker = 0
                Set a = FindNextEmpty(Sheets("SAPdata").Range("F4"))

                If IsInArrayC(anString, SAPanArray) = 0 Then

                Else
                    For j = LBound(SAPbulkArray) To UBound(SAPbulkArray)
                        If InStr((SAPbulkArray(j)), anString) > 0 Then
                            ticker = (1 + ticker)
                        End If

                        If ticker = 1 Then

                        ElseIf ticker = 2 Then
```

OK Forgive me for hack/slashing everything but this helps me read your logical order.

Ticker only really evers needs to be 1 or 0 due to your line of reasoning. The

```
 ElseIf ticker =2
```

Should be

```
 Elseif ticker = 0
```

OR

```
 Else
'some more code
```

So yoyu could save yourself the the trouble UNLESS ticker needs to be greater than 1 ever. So far by what you posted it doesnt need to be.

Comment: I thought that too but there is a `j loop` inside the `i loop` that the OP increments the ticker in `ticker = (1 + ticker)`.

Comment: This is possible answer, more detail needed from OP to say this definitively, though.

Comment: Well it appears this is not the correct answer because ticker needs to reference one or two, so zero does need to reset at the beginning of eahc iteration of i.

Comment: @DavidZemens   does this look right to you?

Comment: That's a good point on the If/Else condition Doug. My only qualm at this point is that, it's not clear OP has done due diligence in debugging and actually identifying the problem -- and if his diagnosis is wrong, then this answer may not actually solve it. He states that `ticker` doesn't increment, but is unable to demonstrate that (via Debug statements, for example). I'm nearly certain that `ticker = ticker + 1` in the Immediate pane would prove him wrong, though :)

Comment: If the searched string `anString` is multiple times in the `SAPanArray` - array then `ticker` should increase. After the first time it is found, it should be 1 and 2 at the second time (3 at the third time and so on). Why do you think it can't be 2? What does prevent it from being 2? I don't get your logic Doug :(

Comment: Well that requires more input from OP @DirkReichal but i def conceed to your point - i was just going off what i saw in the moment. So, you could be right there and an oversight on my part. thanks for catching that. I also qualified that in my response though.

Comment: The format of my comment is terrible, let me change my original question. I am new to this